# Legal age for investing

Tags: investing, trading, israel

What year of age is required to open a brokerage account and start trading? Is it 18+ or 21+? I live in Israel, but am interested in trading in the U.S. markets.

Comment: I’m from Israel but I want to trade on the US markets, so I’m a foreign trader.

Comment: It looks like the age varies by [state of residence](http://www.wisestockbuyer.com/2012/06/can-anyone-buy-stocks/). I’m not sure what this means for an Israel-resident investor. You’d best ask your broker.

Comment: @PeterK. it never would have occurred to me that some states have a 21 year minimum age.  (Contracts can be signed at 18, and I live in a state where you can buy them at 18.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the U.S.,  handful of states allow a citizen to  open a brokerage account at age 18.  In most states the age is 21. A parent or legal guardian can open a Custodial Account for a child who wants to invest but the adult  administers the account (places  the orders).

U.S. citizenship is not required to trade U.S. securities but brokers can put conditions on your market access.  There are international brokers which permit trading in as well as from many countries.

Two brokers considered very good for foreign investment by U.S citizens are  Interactive Brokers and Fidelity.  I would assume that the converse should be true, namely that they would also be good for residents of foreign countries who wish to  invest in the U.S.